# Order join by column from each table

Tags: mysql

If I have 2 tables that both have the same column `ord`

table_a

```
id | value | ord
1  | asd   | 1
2  | dfg   | 5
3  | ghj   | 7
```

table_b

```
id | value | ord
1  | zxc   | 3
2  | cvb   | 4
3  | bnm   | 6
```

How can I join them to get this result

```
| id | value | ord | id | value | ord
| 1  | asd   | 1   | -  |   -   |  -
| -  |   -   |  -  | 1  | zxc   | 3
| -  |   -   |  -  | 2  | cvb   | 4
| 2  | dfg   | 5   | -  |   -   |  -
| -  |   -   |  -  | 1  | bnm   | 6
| 3  | ghj   | 7   | -  |   -   |  -
```

Or if I could not have the empty columns even better.

Basically what I'm trying to ask is if I could join the tables and sort all the results based on columns from the 2 tables, in this example `ord`

When I try

```
SELECT * FROM table_a JOIN table_b ORDER BY ord
```

I get field ambiguous error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.id a_id 
     , a.value a_value
     , a.ord a_ord
     , NULL b_id
     , NULL b_value
     , NULL b_ord 
  FROM table_a a 
 UNION 
SELECT NULL
     , NULL
     , NULL
     , b.* 
  FROM table_b b
 ORDER 
    BY COALESCE(b_ord,a_ord)
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.ord b_ord FROM table_a a UNION SELECT NULL , NULL , NULL ,' at line 6

Comment: Oops fixed - (you're allowed to solve this yourself!)

Comment: Yes there was another slight mistake but it is working, awesome! Thanks!

Comment: Apparently `COALESCE` is the magic word that I was looking for with this question